# Instantiating openzeppelin counter with a defined offset

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

I am working with a contract where it requires me to start the openzeppelin counter with an offset for example

```
uint256 tokenIdCounter = Counters.Counter(nonMintedBeforeLimitReached + LIMIT);
```

Wanted to know if it is valid and will work?

Comment: Yes, it will work.